# Ошибка типа аргумента при использовании капчи

Tags: java, generics, лямбда-выражение

Есть такой код:

```
interface SomeFunc<T> {
    T func(T t);
}

public class LambdaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeFunc<String> reverse = (str) -> {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                result += str.charAt(i);
            }
            return result;
        };

        Rever foo = new Rever();
        foo.doSmth(reverse, "reverse");
    }
}

class Rever {
    public void doSmth(SomeFunc<?> func, String n) {
        System.out.println(func.func(n));
    }
}
```

Но компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> [Java] The method `func(capture#1-of ?)` in the type `SomeFunc<capture#1-of ?>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String)`.

В чем моя ошибка и как это исправить?

Comment: Проблема в этой строчке : (SomeFunc<?> func, String n)
Вы говорите : Возьми любую функцию (SomeFunc<Integer> например)
и передай в нее String. Вместо этого сделайте  (SomeFunc<String> func, String n)

Comment: Либо используйте такой вариант :
 public <T> void doSmth(SomeFunc<T> function, T n)

Comment: @aleshka-batman, думаю это можно опукликовать как ответ. Дополню, что объявление интерфейса `SomeFunc` - лишнее, так как для этих целей в стандартной библиотеке есть `UnaryOperator<T>`, который является наследником `Function<T, T>`

Comment: @aleshka-batman, опубликуйте свой комментарий как ответ. public <T> void doSmth(SomeFunc<T> function, T n) - это то, что нужно. Спасибо.